# Windows 7 NTP is not working to synchronise

Tags: ntp

i have a Windows 7 SP1 PC, and i am trying to synchronising to an internal NTP Server, but is not working. IT is failed. The PC is a part of a domain and the internal server also is in the same domain. Can anyone suggest a possoble solution, why is it happening?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRQek.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjs3D.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `w32tm /query /configuration`  and
`w32tm /query /status`

Comment: Same remark, but copy/paste the output. Unless there's a good reason, avoid linking to external resources.

Answer (score 1):

When you're joined to a domain you'd typically want to keep the time in sync with the domain controller you're authenticating to. Domain controllers sync their time with the domain's PDC, which in turn syncs its own time with an external source.

That should all happen with the default configuration, but I can see from your screenshots that you're currently configured for NTP rather than NT5DS (sync to domain controller.)

Use this command to sync your Windows 7 client to the authenticating domain controller:

`w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update`

There's a decent Technet post here detailing the whole domain time sync setup. Def worth a read :)
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nepapfe/2013/03/01/its-simple-time-configuration-in-active-directory/

One other thing to note: if any machine in the chain is a VM, make sure the hypervisor isn't forcing its time on the VM. I've had domain controller VMs in the past that synced their time with both the hypervisor and PDC which lead to some unpredictability, especially when the skew is too great between the two sources.